# Debugging stops not at a break point with clion

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

[image]

As shown above, the ide stops at a line where I haven't put a break point. I tried recompile the program but it doesn't work, so I have to painfully iterate through every cycle....

Comment: Are you trying to debug a release (optimized) build without debug symbols? If that's the case, you are in for a few surprises. A release build *with* debug symbols improves the situation a bit, but if you really want a predictable debug experience then you need to compile your program *without* optimization and *with* debug symbols/information - it will likely kill performance, but it will make your debugging experience what you expect.

Comment: I am buiding using Debug option provided by Clion, I think it should be ok. I experienced similiar problems before, and I recall I have to copy the code and start another project...

Comment: "I am buiding using Debug option provided by Clion" - That doesn't really help. That could mean "start this program in the debugger" not knowing how it was built. Or "start this program that was built in a release configuration in the debugger". It could also mean "Do a debug build of this program and start it in the debugger". I'm guessing it's the first - since that's what I would expect based on experience with multiple IDE's going back 20+ years.   Also; why is this extra information not *in* your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue with Clion display. Though I clicked off the break point and there is not a dot before the line, the break point still exists. I have to open the break point viewer and cancel it from there.